# jQuery : How to addClass to the images on other forms & not on the image above the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 different forms on same page & i need to addClass on the images on the others forms & not on the image above the button when the mouse is hover this one by jQuery.

Here my code :

```
<form id="register_form1">
<div class="register_img">
    <img src="images/register.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="input-btn-reg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">
        <h6>Register</h6>
    </button>
</div>
<form id="register_form2">
<div class="register_img">
    <img src="images/register.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="input-btn-reg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">
        <h6>Register</h6>
    </button>
</div>
<form id="register_form3">
<div class="register_img">
    <img src="images/register.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="input-btn-reg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">
        <h6>Register</h6>
    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: just a googling will give  you this result http://fiddle.jshell.net/nikhilmangal/nupujegc/light/

Comment: you should be specific in your question if you need additional info

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".register_img img").attr("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="register_img">
    <img src="images/register.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="input-btn-reg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" id="btn" onclick="clickbtn()">
        <h6>Register</h6>
    </button>
</div>    

function clickbtn()
        {
            var img = $('.register_img img').attr('src');
            alert(img);
        }
```

OR

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var img = $('.register_img img').attr('src');
        alert(img);
    });
 });
```

Comment: haha...yes its amazing. even i didnot noticed. Let me make the changes

Comment: Thank you, but i have 3 different form on same page & i need to get the img src above the button i click on the button...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function geturl(){
      var src = $('#myImg').attr('src');
      alert(src);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="register_form">
<div class="register_img">
    <img id="myImg" style="height:200px;width:200px" src="http://lmsotfy.com/so.png" />
</div>
<div class="input-btn-reg">
    <button type="submit" onclick="geturl();" class="btn btn-lg">
        <h6>Register</h6>
    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a selector. If you know using [jquery selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/), you can access to your element. then you can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
alert( $('img').attr('src') );
alert( $('img')[0].src );
alert( $('.register_img img').attr('src'));
```

In your example all of codes above will meet your need.